# Apache restrict /var/www subdirectories access

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, redirect

I got 2 virtualhosts that are looking at `/var/www/site1` (ServerName `site1`) and `/var/www/site2` (ServerName `site2`). I want to make my sites unavailable by `http://1.2.3.4/site1` or `http://1.2.3.4/site2` by setting a rewrite rule in a default config (`000-default.conf`):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1\.2\.3\.4 
RewriteRule (.*) http://test.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but sites are still available at `http://1.2.3.4/site1` and `http://1.2.3.4/site1` (although redirect works for `http://1.2.3.4/`).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: No, that does not work(. It is still available(.

Answer (score 1):

There is a thing i cannot understand in the way you have described your setup :

- `http://1.2.3.4/site1` should return a 404.

and

- `http://1.2.3.4/site2` should return a 404.

---

However this could help :

The [doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#vhosts) says :

> By default, `mod_rewrite` configuration settings from the main server
>   context are not inherited by virtual hosts. To make the main server
>   settings apply to virtual hosts, you must place the following
>   directives in each `<VirtualHost>` section:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

So, my advice would be to define `RewriteOptions Inherit` for each `<VirtualHost>` you have.